# How to make space between spannable string in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

## Code:

```
private void setSpans(Editable s, @ColorInt int backgroundColor) {

    BackgroundColorSpan[] spans = s.getSpans(0, s.length(), BackgroundColorSpan.class);
    String[] words;
    if (s.toString().endsWith(" ")) {
        words = (s.toString() + "X").split("\\s");
    } else {
        words = s.toString().split("\\s");
    }
    int completedWordsCount = words.length - 1;
    if (spans.length != completedWordsCount) {
        for (BackgroundColorSpan span : spans) {
            s.removeSpan(span);
        }

        int currentIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length-1; i++) {
            s.setSpan(new CustomDrawble(Color.GRAY, Color.WHITE), currentIndex, currentIndex + words[i].length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            currentIndex += words[i].length() + 1;
        }
    }
```

Above function is useful for creating `spannable String` and to add `Border` to it. I am calling following class:

```
public class CustomDrawble extends ReplacementSpan {

private int mBackgroundColor;
private int mForegroundColor;

public CustomDrawble(int backgroundColor, int foregroundColor) {
    this.mBackgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    this.mForegroundColor = foregroundColor;
}

@Override
public int getSize(Paint paint, CharSequence text, int start, int end, Paint.FontMetricsInt fm) {
    return Math.round(measureText(paint, text, start, end));

}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, CharSequence text, int start, int end, float x, int top, int y, int bottom, Paint paint) {
    float padding = 4f;

    RectF rect = new RectF(x, top + 3, x + measureText(paint, text, start, end) + 10, bottom + 10);
    paint.setColor(mBackgroundColor);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, 10,10,paint);
    paint.setColor(mForegroundColor);
    canvas.drawText(text, start, end, x, y, paint);

}

private float measureText(Paint paint, CharSequence text, int start, int end) {
    return paint.measureText(text, start, end);
}
}
```

The result I am getting from above is:

[image]

The problem with the above code is:

- How to add space between two `spannable` strings?
- How can I add space at the starting of rectangle and first character of a string similar to end of rectangle. I tried to add the space by this code :

  ```
   RectF rect = new RectF(x+10, top + 3, x + measureText(paint, text, start, end) + 10, bottom + 10);
  ```

but it gave me this distorted result:

[image]

If I am not wrong then the problem with the above code is there are not enough spaces between two `spannable` strings.

How can I make it correct?

## Edit-1

Used this  `RectF rect = new RectF(x - 5, top + 3, x + measureText(paint, text, start, end)+5, bottom + 10);`

[image]

Look at the first one it's slightly cutting from starting point. But If I used the above configuration I don't have enough space in two strings. This is the main Issue.

Answer (score 1):

Removing extra pixels from end of your `rect` will solve the problem of having no space between spans

so remove `+ 10` from param for right

like this:

```
RectF rect = new RectF(x, top + 3, x + measureText(paint, text, start, end), bottom + 10);
```

also to add space at starting put some negative margin at starting 
like this:

```
 RectF rect = new RectF(x - 5, top + 3, x + measureText(paint, text, start, end), bottom + 10);
```

following image will explain this visually:

[image: dig]

Comment: Actually I have tried negative value before posting this question :)
 BTW have a checkout the latest arrangement in Edit-1 section

Comment: For your edit 1 you can shred few more pixels from both left and Right. So instead of 5 pixels both sides try with 3

Comment: Actually that's why I asked in the question : How to provide space between two spannable strings :)

Comment: Yes, I got your question :) and reducing padding around your string the way  I explained in answer and previous comment will help.

Comment: I am trying and will let you know

Comment: `RectF rect = new RectF(x - 3, top + 3, x + measureText(paint, text, start, end)+3, bottom + 10)` try this

Comment: I tried and I am fine with the space :P I am playing with this thing from couple of hours :(
Here is the URL : http://i.imgur.com/Gr4HqsF.png

Is it possible to handle the first block because It is slightly cut from the starting

Comment: Try giving some `android:padding` to your `EditText`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93249/discussion-between-user4567-and-rahul-tiwari).